# How to check a VPS virtualization

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, vps, xen

How do I check whether my VPS is OpenVZ or XEN? (I ordered a while back and don't remember exactly which plan I ordered!).

OS: Linux running ubuntu.

thanks

JP

Comment: Post the output of `$ uname -a`.

Comment: Linux ......com 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Nov 9 13:35:30 EST 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux. So looks like it is xen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow the examples of detection used by Puppet and Facter you can check the /proc filesystem for hints.

The existence of `/proc/vz/veinfo` would indicate you're running OpenVZ but the existence of `/proc/vz/version` will tell you whether it's openvzhn or openvzve.

Next you can look for either `/proc/sys/xen`, `/sys/bus/xen` or `/proc/xen` to see if you're running Xen but look for `/proc/xen/capabilities` to tell if it's a dom0 or domU.

Comment: If he's got a VPS through a host, I'd certainly hope it wasn't a dom0. :)

Comment: /proc/sys/xen is present, but /proc/vz/veinfo is not, so its Xen. /proc/xen/capabilities is empty.  Could you please tell what is dom0/domU and why is dom0 not good? :)

Comment: dom0 is the privileged instance... basically the host machine... domU is the unprivileged virtual machine.

Comment: How about checking vmware and others?

Comment: @Rafael Check into the logic of the Facter virtual fact as it is able to determine the differences. I have an ESXi server and the VMs running Puppet are able to determine that they are vmware based.

Comment: @JeremyBouse I just checked it out at http://git.io/xKacLA It looks for the video card name using lspci command, which contains vmware word in the adapter name :D thank you